# Replace values in XML-driven dropdown list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In my form, when a user selects a REGION, a dropdown menu populates from a xml file. I have multiple options in a REGION. Right now, when a user selects a different option the DROPDOWN list "appends". I would like it to REPLACE. Any ideas on how to adjust this code to do this?

PS... I know that in the JS code I have an "AppendTo" method. Its just a working placeholder for functionality.

```
DROPDOWN HTML:
<select class="t2_drop_field" id="AppType1"></select>

REGION SELECT HTML:
<select name="OBKey__500_1" id="Region" multiple onchange="setAppOptions()">
    <option>Area 1</option>
    <option>Area 1</option>
</select>



var e = document.getElementById("Region");
var eVal=e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;

if (eVal == "J15 KY B" || eVal == "J15 OH B")
    {
            $(document).ready(function() {
            var app_data;      

             // Loading APP
             $.get('pe_form_options.xml', function(data) {
                 app_data = data;
                 var that = $('#AppType1');
                    $('RegionB', app_data).each(function() {
                       $('<option />', { 
                           text: $(this).text(),
                           value: $(this).attr('index')
                       }).appendTo(that);
                    });
             }, 'xml');
         });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a little more straight forward then I thought. Thanks for all the help everyone.

```
     var dv = document.getElementById('AppType1').value;
        if (dv != ""){
            document.getElementById('AppType1').options.length = 0;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure this is what you want, but in order to replace the options in the `<select>`, you'd need to remove the old ones, before adding the new.

The easiest way to do this would be to modify your code like so:

```
...
var that = $('#AppType1');
that.find('option').remove();
$('<option />', { 
    text: $(this).text(),
    value: $(this).attr('index')
}).appendTo(that);
...
```

The line I added `that.find('option').remove();` finds all `<option>` tags under the `<select>` tag and removes them.